# searching a string in multiple docs and note pad documents

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, search, windows-search, notepad

I have multiple files in docx format and notepad .txt files.

I want to search for a particular string like #search string# it might be present in any of the multiple docx or .txt or .rtf files.
Is there a way to do easily rather than opening each document one by one and searching them.
I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Explorer will do this.  Make sure you're at the folder level you want to be and in the Search box put Content: Search String

There's a world of search capabilities in Explorer if you're willing to dig into special syntax and Boolean search language.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference

Otherwise getting hold of a good file manager, there are several out there, will give you similar search capabilities with much better user interfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and giving microsoft link I was not aware of any such thing.